# Why IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print alternatively using three threads.
First thread should print one number, then second thread the second number , then third thread. I try to implement it using a shared static integer but my code is showing IllegalMonitorStateException. Can anyone please check this and tell my mistake?

```
class ThreadRevisit extends Thread
{
static Integer number;
int num;
ThreadRevisit(String name,Integer number,int num)
{
  super(name);
  this.number=number;
  this.num=num;
}

 public void run()
{
  int n= number;
  do
  {
  synchronized(ThreadRevisit.number)
       {
           if(n>100)
           {
           number.notifyAll();
           break;
           }
           if (n%3==num)
           {
              System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+num);
              number=number+1;
           }
            number.notifyAll();
            try
            {
             number.wait();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
       }
     }
   while(true);

    } 
}
class T1
{
public static void main(String[] ar) 
 {
 Integer inn=new Integer(0);
 ThreadRevisit.number=inn;
 ThreadRevisit t1=new ThreadRevisit("one",inn,0);
 ThreadRevisit t2=new ThreadRevisit("two",inn,1);
 ThreadRevisit t3=new ThreadRevisit("three",inn,2);

 t1.start();
 t2.start();
 t3.start();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in line 27

```
number=number+1;
```

You effectively change object number to a new one with increased value. So the new one has no monitor attached and this results with an error.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem in your code (actually the same as mentioned by Marcin Krasowski): you reassign the Integer variable. This means there is another instance in play and the wait/notify will occur on the wrong Integer object.

I have never quite liked the wait/notify methods, you could also look using the observer pattern, where the second thread observes the first thread to have written its output and the third thread observing the second for the same.

Answer (score 0):

[IllegalMonitorStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

As correctly stated by Marcin Krasowski, the number has been changed. 
You locked number with

```
synchronized(ThreadRevisit.number)
```

Later you have changed the `number`.

By the time you are calling `notifyAll()`, you don't have lock on number object on which you acquired the lock initially.

You should avoid changing the object, on which you acquire the lock.